# How to determine if the language is LL(1)?

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

```
P → PL | L
L → N; | M; | C
N → print E
M → print "W"
W → TW | ε
C → if E {P} | if E {P} else {P}
E → (EOE) | V (note: this has a variable O)
O → + | - | *
V → 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 (note: this has a terminal 0 (zero))
T → a | b | c | d
```

For the above grammar G, is it not LL(1) because it evokes FIRST/FIRST conflict when trying to predict the production of P?
I am really struggling on how to prove that it is not LL(1)...
Any help or advice would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

A left-recursive grammar cannot be LL(k) for any *k*. `P →  P L` is left-recursive.

In addition, `L` has two productions starting with the same terminal, so it is impossible to choose between them with only one symbol of lookahead.